# downgrade php from 5.6.9 to 5.3.3 debian jessie

Tags: php, debian, downgrade

We have a php application which running on debian squeeze server.

When i install it on the new server (debian jessie), it doesn't run properly.

how can i downgrade php from 5.6.9 to 5.3.3?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better idea to fix the application?

Comment: no, currently  we can't

Comment: Download the binary from http://php.net/releases/ and compile it for your Linux distro

Comment: I would not try to compile it from source, so I disagree with MonkeyZeus.
Instead see this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/913792/php-5-3-10-on-debian-jessie

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of PHP used in Squeeze is 5.3.3.

Add the Squeeze repos in your source list:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

Update package list:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Uninstall current PHP version:

```
dpkg -r --force-depends $(dpkg -l | grep php | awk '{print $2}')
```

Install same PHP packages using squeeze repo:

```
apt-get install -t "squeeze" $(dpkg -l | grep php | awk '{print $2}')
```

Note: I use this to downgrade PHP from Squeeze-s PHP 5.3 to Lenny's PHP 5.2, it should works from Jessie to Squeeze.

Comment: Thx for your response. I use this steps and i have a problem of conflict packages.
Finally i use some step for install php5.3.3 on debian 8.
I execute step 1 and 2, after that I run this command $ apt-get install -t "squeeze" apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork php5 php5-cli php5-dev

Comment: In any ways I do, apt returns this error: dpkg : Breaks: libapache2-mod-php5 (< 5.6.4+dfsg-3~) but 5.3.3-7+squeeze18 is to be installed, I have to install libapache2-mod-php5 manually, but I don't understand how can I fix this "breaks" error (the module works well).

Comment: I think libapache2-mod-php5 is not selected by the dpkg command. Add it to the list of packages to be uninstalled and then installed in Squeeze version.